# How do I stop my UI from appearing more than once, after the player has clicked "Accept Quest", within the UI window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Right now, whenever the player goes on the quest, and walks back on himself, the UI window pops up again that says to accept the quest again, when the player already has done so. I also don't want the accept quest window popping up once the player returns to the NPC to collect their reward, this is why I only want the UI to only be able to appear once.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestGiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Quest quest;

    public MovementTest player;

    public GameObject questWindow;
    public Text titleText;
    public Text descriptionText;

    public void OpenQuestWindow()
    {
        if (isQuestAccepted)
            return;
        questWindow.SetActive(true);
        titleText.text = quest.title;
        descriptionText.text = quest.description;

    }

    public void AcceptQuest()
    {
        questWindow.SetActive(false);
        quest.isActive = true;
        player.quest = quest;
    }



    void Start()
    {
        
        questWindow = GameObject.Find("QuestWindow");

        questWindow.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you set isQuestAccepted = true ; in AcceptQuest() ? ... and looks like you didnt define bool isQuestAccepted anywhere in the script. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the provided code, `isQuestAccepted` is not being set to `true` when accepting the quest.
Try to add it in the `AcceptQuest` method:

```
public void AcceptQuest()
{
    isQuestAccepted = true;
    questWindow.SetActive(false);
    quest.isActive = true;
    player.quest = quest;
}
```

To make sure, please provide more details about the `isQuestAccepted` flag and the triggers for calling `OpenQuestWindow`

Generraly speaking, some things to consider:

- By the looks of it, the execution of the method is limited once per the **lifetime** of the `QuestGiver`. It is recommended for quest models to have a persistent value between executions.
- is it possible `questWindow.SetActive` being called outside the scope of provided code?
- If the quest is already accepted then you should not execute `OpenQuestWindow` in the first place.